# TA-LIB is not getting imported in canopy?

Tags: python, ta-lib

I am using canopy 1.5.2.2785 version i followed

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQPvj.png): https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib for installation of TA-LIB in ubantu 14.04 LTS.
1]untar and cd  2] ./configure --prefix=/usr 3] make 4] sudo make install

followed the exact commands written above(untar manualy)
As a result following log generated in the command prompt[image]

After this when i tried to import the package in canopy "ImportError: No module named talib" error occured.

following is the log of make command 
[image: log of make]

Can someone help me out here whats the issue ?

Comment: It's not a full log, isn't? I would better look into `make` output rather `make install`. Are you able to file `talib*` files in '/usr/lib',  '/usr/local/lib',          '/usr/lib64',   '/usr/local/lib64',       '/opt/lib',      '/opt/local/lib' ?

Comment: Yes i found the talib* file in the usr/local/lib folder plus i have added the make output in the question